# Proving that the signature of edges cannot define graphs with perfect matching

Tags: graph-theory, first-order-logic, matching-theory

I have the signature $\sigma := \{E\}$ (E is a double symbol relation, which represents if there is an edge between two vertices, e.g. $E_{1,2}$ means there is an edge between vertex 1 and 2).

Now I need to show that the set of all graphs with minimum one perfect matching **cannot** be defined in first order logic (quantificational logic).

I already showed (just by stating the formal) that when $\sigma = \{E,M\}$ (M is the relation saying if two vertices have a matching), then the set is defined using first order logic.

Any tips on how I can begin my proof? From what I've understood, I should start it by showing that the set of such graphs is infinite, while the set of perfect matchings is finite. But from there I don't know how to use my relation symbol $E$ in that proof.

*Long story short: I need to show that if I'm allowed to use only the edges relation, I cannot define graphs with perfect matching.*

Comment: I am guessing that both $E,M$ are symbols for binary (two argument) predicates.  You have in mind, I suspect, that theories will have an *intended interpretation* on models that happen to be simple undirected graphs, in which $E(x,y)$ means that  $x,y$ are vertices joined by an edge while $M(x,y)$ means an edge between $$ is in the matching. Am I following the setup correctly?

Comment: @hardmath correct. And I should show that if I don't have the M symbol, it is basically not possible to define a formal in predicates logic for the problem above. with an M symbol it is easy to define such a formal.